# Suggestion to design a devices stock mysql database tables for a planning events web app

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

What I have, a stock of devices that will consist of:

- 5 printers
- 5 phones
- 5 routers
- 5 UPS

And all that devices I rent them to be used on all kind of events (outside party, weddings and so on), this devices are used with another app to keep track of food orders to help waiters.

Now I plan to develop a web app that will help me to see if I have available devices to plan events and rent my devices. For example: someone is planning 1 event in 01.08.2017 and will need 3 printers 3 phones 3 routers and 1 UPS, another client will plan a event on 20.07.2017 that will need 4 printers 4 phones 4 routers and 1 UPS, and let's say someone will ask a event on 28.07.2017 that will needing 3 printers 3 phones 3 routers and 1 UPS, I will need to check on a date picker if the 28.07.2017  date that I will have available that device request ( in our case no, because there is a event on 01.08.2017), another note, let's put a 1 week time that the client will return the devices, so the 1 week will be the gap for returning time. And the same category devices will be considered same in a sense that for me it won't count if I have phone1 or phone4 available, for me will be still 1 phone free that I can use exemple phone1 == phone2 same for other devices(all are same model) .

What I'm thinking for the tables is something like this:

```
devices_type:

id    name
1     printer
2     android phone
3     router
4     UPS

devices_stock:

id    id_type    name       is_available
1     1          printer1   0
2     1          printer2   1
3     1          printer3   1
4     1          printer4   0
5     1          printer5   1
6     2          router1    1
.....
(and same for phones,wifi and ups)
events:
id    device_type    device_id    rented_start    rented_end
1     2              6            20.07.2017      27.07.2017
2     1              2            01.08.2017      08.08.2017 
3     1              3            28.07.2017      04.08.2017
```

In the end I will want to select a date and check if I can rent the devices or not providing the number of them needed, but I will start on mysql tables design, but I feel that I miss something in my structure, any help and suggestion for a better table structure for my need?

Comment: The is_available column, is that an indicator of availability other than by date/time? For instance, the device is damaged or under repair, so it's set to 0. If it's to indicate availability base on datetime I'd get rid of it.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider adding one more timestamp column for "due_back". This could be used to show as not available, but different from rented_end for billing purposes. It could also be updated when the item is actually returned.

Comment: I will put it available if it's not reserved for a rent, for example I plan to rent 4 phones and 1 will be free, and I will check with the date I should see If I have phone on stock and what is reserved and on what date.

Comment: And due_back is what my field rented_end is doing! (it will auto add 1 week from the event date when I expect to get that devices back).

Comment: That seems redundant, and something that could cause problems down the road. Since you can determine availability "on the fly" based on datetime, having a column like is_available (other than in a view) is not needed. Also, it isn't datetime sensitive. IOW, it might be available on Tuesday, but not Wednesday, so it's irrelevant and incorrect.

Comment: Also I think I will need some new column on events table to list the actual event name where devices are needed, in order to get them in my date picker.

Comment: Also, maybe the events table should be event_devices_reserved (or similar) and a separate table for events with name, event_date, contact info, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming something like this is what you're after, which would at least display the devices available.

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.device_id, S.name AS Device_Name
FROM devices_stock S, devices_rented R
WHERE 'date' < R.rented_start AND 'date' > R.rented_end AND S.device_id = R.device_id AND S.is_available != 0
```